# Why cant I call the method in protocol which uses swift Generics?

Tags: generics, swift3, swift-protocols

I know the title of the question is not correct for the question. But I could not come up with better title, Ill modify if somebody suggests a better title.

Here is the question:

I have a protocol,

```
import Foundation

protocol MyFilter {
    var currentlySelected : Bool { get set }
    func configure<T> (filterInfo : T) where T: MyGenericDataModel
}
```

This asks all the confirming classes to declare a variable named currentlySelected and also expects to write a method that takes a single parameter that confirms to MyGenericDataModel protocol.

MyGenericDataModel looks like,

```
import Foundation

protocol MyGenericDataModel {
    init(data : JSON)
}
```

There are multiple classes that confirms to MyGenericDataModel. Like,

```
struct MyDataModel1 : MyGenericDataModel {
    var id : String? = nil
    //other properties

    init(data : JSON) {
    }
}

struct MyDataModel2 : MyGenericDataModel {
    var id : String? = nil
    //other properties

    init(data : JSON) {
    }
}
```

and so on.

Now I get the array of data which can be any of the custom data model. So I declared a array of objects which confirms to MyGenericDataModel protocol.

```
var passedDataSource: Array< MyGenericDataModel>? = nil
```

Now I need to call the method of MyFilter,

```
let filterInfo = passedDataSource![indexPath.row]
abcd.configure(filterInfo: filterInfoToPass)
```

Where abcd obviously confirms to MyFilter thats why I can call configure on it.

**Issue**

Xcode gives compilation error saying,

> Can not invoke 'configure' with an argument list of type '(filterInfo:
>   MyGenericDataModel)

**EDIT:**

As per luk2302's comment, I am posting the implementation details of class of abcd :)

```
class MyCellClass: UICollectionViewCell, MyFilter{
    var currentlySelected : Bool = false
    func configure<T>(filterInfo: T) where T : MyGenericDataModel {
       //use filter info
       //perform some UI operations to update cell UI
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you would show what `abcd` you would present a *fully* working example.

Comment: Is there *any* reason for the use of generics at all? Why not use `func configure (filterInfo : MyGenericDataModel)` instead?

Comment: @luk2302 : Sure sir! Lemme post the implementation of abcd class and as for your second question why Generics at all, I was trying to learn the concept hence I decided to declare it as Generics :)

Comment: Try changing the signature of configure to `func configure<T: MyGenericDataModel> (filterInfo : T)`

Comment: @mark-brownsword : Tried :( no benefit still same error appears :(

Comment: What does Xcode think the input parameter type should be, is there a hint for type?

Comment: No, Xcode does not show any further details. It has a problem if I pass the parameter of type MyGenericDataModel on the other hand if I pass parameter of type MyDataModel1 which confirms to MyGenericDataModel it accepts without any complains

Comment: Is that `filterInfo` variable name wrong? It should be `let filterInfoToPass = passedDataSource![indexPath.row]`

Comment: Nope :) Sorry that was copy paste mistake, I could not post the original source code hence tried renaming variables and removed all un related logics in question. While copy pasting I did mistake :)

Comment: Because [protocols don't conform to themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself), you cannot use `MyGenericDataModel` as a type that conforms to `MyGenericDataModel`.

Comment: @hamish : Bingo :) Perfect answer :) Up voted both question and answer :) Thank you for the link :)